# VBScript Error 80040E14 Syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: csv, vbscript, active-directory

I'm trying to use a script I found on the internet to allow the bulk creation of new user accounts in Active Directory using VBScript and a CSV file. I'm not using CSVDE b/c this script will also create passwords. I keep encountering this error when running the code I cannot figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
'*********************************************************************
' Script: createUsersFromCSV.vbs                                     *
' Creates new user accounts in Active Directory from a CSV file.     *
' Input: CSV file with layout logonname,firstname,lastname,password  *
'                                                                    *
'*********************************************************************

Option Explicit

Dim sCSVFileLocation
Dim sCSVFile
Dim oConnection
Dim oRecordSet
Dim oNewUser

' Variables needed for LDAP connection
Dim oRootLDAP
Dim oContainer

' Holding variables for information import from CSV file
Dim sLogon
Dim sFirstName
Dim sLastName
Dim sDisplayName
Dim sPassword
Dim nPwdLastSet
Dim nUserAccountControl ' Used to enable the account
Dim sDomain
Dim sCompany
Dim sPhone
Dim sEmail
Dim sDescription

Dim NumChar, Count, strRdm, intRdm
Dim fso, f, fso1, f1

'* Modify this to match your company's AD domain
sDomain="mydomain.local"

'* Input file location
sCSVFileLocation = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\" 'KEEP TRAILING SLASH!

'* Full path to input file
sCSVFile = sCSVFileLocation&"newusers.csv"

' Commands used to open the CSV file and select all of the records
set oConnection = createobject("adodb.connection")
set oRecordSet = createobject("adodb.recordset")
oConnection.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & _
sCSVFileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
oRecordSet.open "SELECT * FROM " & sCSVFile ,oConnection

' Create a connection to an Active Directory OU container.
Set oRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set oContainer = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Test," & _
oRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

on error resume next 

do until oRecordSet.EOF ' Reads the values (cells) in the sInputFile file.



   ' --------- Start creating user account
   ' Read variable information from the CSV file
   ' and build everything needed to create the account
   sLogon = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).value
   sFirstName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(1).value
   sLastName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(2).value
   sDisplayName = sFirstName&" "&sLastName
   sPassword = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(3).value

   ' Build the User account
Set oNewUser = oContainer.Create("User","cn="&sFirstName&" "&sLastName)
oNewUser.put "sAMAccountName",lcase(sLogon)
oNewUser.put "givenName",sFirstName
oNewUser.put "sn",sLastName
oNewUser.put "UserPrincipalName",lcase(SLogon)&"@"&sDomain
oNewUser.put "DisplayName",sDisplayName
oNewUser.put "name",lcase(sLogon)

' Write this information into Active Directory so we can
' modify the password and enable the user account
oNewUser.SetInfo

' Change the users password
oNewUser.SetPassword sPassword
oNewUser.Put "pwdLastSet", 0

' Enable the user account
oNewUser.Put "userAccountControl", 512
oNewUser.SetInfo


objFile.Close

'*******************
oRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
'*******************
' Used only for debugging
'if err.number = -2147019886 then
' msgbox "User logon " & sLogon & "already exists"
'End If
' --------- End of user account creation
```

Here is where the error is occuring, line 51 char 1:

```
oRecordSet.open "SELECT * FROM " & sCSVFile ,oConnection
```

Comment: You need to select `FROM` a tablename, not a filepath.

Comment: Its pulling from the CSV file. @fmunkert figured out a workaround that helped me determined the folder I was running from was screwing things up. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `sCSVFile` contains special characters and therefore must be escaped like this:

```
oRecordSet.open "SELECT * FROM [" & sCSVFile & "]", oConnection
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: That definitely helped, and I figured out why I got the error in the first place, it had to do with the directory in which the script and csv file were. I have them in a directory in which that line of code has no errors without your modification. Now I get this error instead:



80072030 There is no such object on the server.




`Set oContainer = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Test," & _`





I know for a fact one of our OUs is named Test....

Comment: I actually got this working yesterday. If anyone would like the code let me know. The problem had to do with the folder I was running the script from. The code was actually ok. I've also modified the code to prompt the user to enter the name of the OU they want the new account created in. Works perfectly.